# Creating a firmlink in /usr on MacOS 10.15 & 11

Tags: macos, mac, sip

I cannot disable SIP to make **/** (root filesystem) writeable in my environment, so I'm trying to figure out how to create a synthetic firmlink in /usr instead.

I have no problem creating firmlinks under **/** by adding entries in **/etc/synthetic.conf** but cannot create one under **/usr**.

Tried this in **/etc/synthetic.conf** with a reboot but it doesn't work:

```
usr/config          System/Volumes/Data/config
```

Any tip (rather than disabling/enabling SIP or using /usr/local) would be very much appreciated, if there's a way. Thanks!

Comment: Why does it need to be in /usr that has always been where the vendor of the OS puts things

Comment: Some software installs stuff under /usr and users cannot change the path.

Comment: Which software as a matter of interest? I would ask the producer how it should be installed on BigSur

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entries in the **synthetic.conf** *file* pertain only to the *root mount point*.

Reading the entire manual page it is quite clear the intent is that entries are only capable of being created at `/` and not beyond it.

From the **DESCRIPTION** section of the **synthetic.conf** manual page:

> **synthetic.conf** describes virtual symbolic links and empty directories to be created at the root mount point. Because the root mount point is read-only as of macOS 10.15, physical files may not be created at this location. All writeable paths must reside on the data volume, which is mounted at /System/Volumes/Data.
>
> **synthetic.conf** provides a mechanism for some limited, user-controlled file-creation at /.  The synthetic entities described in this file are synthesized by the kernel during early system boot. They are not physically present on the disk, but when the system is booted, they behave as if they were within certain parameters.
>
> **synthetic.conf** is intended to be used for creating mount points at /